# How to submit button value from view to controller through model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm use two submit  buttons named Accept and Reject.
I'm submitting model value from both Model

```
 My conroller
 public ActionResult MyAction(Model model)
{

}
```

My View

```
@model Model
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = 
"multipart/form-data" }))
{
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-rounded" asp-for=Model.Response value="true">Approved</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-rounded" asp-for=Model.Response value="false">Reject</button>
}
```

My 'Response'  is boolean type. How can submit true or false value on button submit through model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass the button value, you need to add the `name` attribute in the `<button>` element.

Note that the `asp-for` (which is the [Input Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-input-tag-helper)) only works for the `<input>` element. Hence it won't generate the `id` and `name` attributes in the `<button>` elements. Remove the `asp-for` tag helper as it is not needed.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-rounded" value="true" name="Response">Approved</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-rounded" value="false" name="Response">Reject</button>
```

[image]